# What does __init__ method return in python

Tags: python

```
class Num:
   def __init__(self,num):
      self.n = num
```

I read that the `__init__` method returns `None`.When I perform `a=Num(5)`, `Num(5)` will call `__init__` method of the class.But if `__init__`  returns `None` then `a` should reference nothing.But instead `a` is referencing the object of `Num` Class.How does it happen?So does `__init__` return `None` or the object of the class?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`__init__()` returns `None`. It is [`__new__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) that returns the new instance.

Comment: +1 (correct) It seems like your confusion stemmed from thinking that `__init__()` was the only method called when instantiating an object; `a=Num(5)` is not the same as `a=Num.__init__(5)` (note that the second one doesn't work).

Comment: +1 for __init__() is not the only method called.Thnx @MatthewAdams

Answer (score 2):

When doing a=Num(5), you do create the object and the newly created object is returned. But it is not as easy as you would directly call `__init__` when creating the object. 
`__init__` is called as part of the initiation process by some Python magic in the background. And basically the `__new__` is part of that magic. However, there are only rare cases, where you want to fiddle with `__new__`. You should only do so, if you really know what you are doing and if there are really no easier ways to reach your goal.